# How does one detect training instabilities in DQN?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, training, dqn, stability

I am curious what training instabilities look like in a standard dqn, with or without a target network. I'm assuming the loss function would never converge since the difference between the predicted q-values and td-target would not reduce. I'd like it if someone could give more identifying symptoms of this problem.